# Avoiding HTML and Scripts tags renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I've been working in a Chat Box, I use Node.js + socket.io for client-server communication so I can't execute PHP code(I've read that is possible but It's not recommended and difficult to achieve). Everything works fine except when users send messages with HTML or Scripts tags.

I've tried to remove those tags with a function that I found in [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/). It works fine, but only for HTML tags, then I thought: Well, I can remove Script tags first using regular expressions. Something like this

`.replace(/<script.*>.*<\/script>/ims, " ")`

and then remove the HTML tags, but I'm not sure if this method is hacks proof, **and that's a lot of processes for each message sent.**

Is there any form of appending text`$("#div").append(message);` without rendering HTML/JavaScript code ? --- Print the text just the way it is, like in [twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv/), in there, if you send a message with HTML/JS/PHP code, the message is printed just like the way you type it.

or, is there any other way to remove tags ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can call `.text()` function.

Comment: .append() appends to the div. .text() will replace the entire div. Not a good idea IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append a div with the message set as text.

```
$("#div").append( $("<div>").text(message) );
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks, it worked. I think this time I went to far away from the easiest solution

Comment: I just realized that, it's adding me a break line at the end for each append I do in that way. How could I fix it ? Thank you.